# Unity 2D build to android gives errors

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, 2d

I am trying to build my game for android. I am using the latest untiy version 2022.3.5f1 and am building directly to my phone (build & run).

Every time these 3 errors pop up.

1:

```
Exception while marshalling C:\Program Files\Unity\Hub\Editor\2022.3.5f1\Editor\Data\PlaybackEngines\AndroidPlayer\SDK\build-tools\32.0.0\package.xml. Probably the SDK is read-only
Exception while marshalling C:\Program Files\Unity\Hub\Editor\2022.3.5f1\Editor\Data\PlaybackEngines\AndroidPlayer\SDK\platform-tools\package.xml. Probably the SDK is read-only
Exception while marshalling C:\Program Files\Unity\Hub\Editor\2022.3.5f1\Editor\Data\PlaybackEngines\AndroidPlayer\SDK\platforms\android-31\package.xml. Probably the SDK is read-only
Exception while marshalling C:\Program Files\Unity\Hub\Editor\2022.3.5f1\Editor\Data\PlaybackEngines\AndroidPlayer\SDK\platforms\android-32\package.xml. Probably the SDK is read-only
Exception while marshalling C:\Program Files\Unity\Hub\Editor\2022.3.5f1\Editor\Data\PlaybackEngines\AndroidPlayer\SDK\tools\package.xml. Probably the SDK is read-only
Exception while marshalling C:\Program Files\Unity\Hub\Editor\2022.3.5f1\Editor\Data\PlaybackEngines\AndroidPlayer\SDK\build-tools\32.0.0\package.xml. Probably the SDK is read-only
Exception while marshalling C:\Program Files\Unity\Hub\Editor\2022.3.5f1\Editor\Data\PlaybackEngines\AndroidPlayer\SDK\platform-tools\package.xml. Probably the SDK is read-only
Exception while marshalling C:\Program Files\Unity\Hub\Editor\2022.3.5f1\Editor\Data\PlaybackEngines\AndroidPlayer\SDK\platforms\android-31\package.xml. Probably the SDK is read-only
Exception while marshalling C:\Program Files\Unity\Hub\Editor\2022.3.5f1\Editor\Data\PlaybackEngines\AndroidPlayer\SDK\platforms\android-32\package.xml. Probably the SDK is read-only
Exception while marshalling C:\Program Files\Unity\Hub\Editor\2022.3.5f1\Editor\Data\PlaybackEngines\AndroidPlayer\SDK\tools\package.xml. Probably the SDK is read-only
> Task :launcher:preBuild UP-TO-DATE
> Task :unityLibrary:preBuild UP-TO-DATE
> Task :launcher:preDebugBuild UP-TO-DATE
> Task :unityLibrary:preDebugBuild UP-TO-DATE
> Task :launcher:mergeDebugNativeDebugMetadata NO-SOURCE
> Task :unityLibrary:compileDebugAidl NO-SOURCE
> Task :launcher:generateDebugBuildConfig UP-TO-DATE
> Task :unityLibrary:packageDebugRenderscript NO-SOURCE
> Task :launcher:compileDebugAidl NO-SOURCE
> Task :unityLibrary:writeDebugAarMetadata UP-TO-DATE
> Task :launcher:compileDebugRenderscript NO-SOURCE
> Task :unityLibrary:compileDebugRenderscript NO-SOURCE
> Task :launcher:javaPreCompileDebug UP-TO-DATE
> Task :unityLibrary:generateDebugResValues UP-TO-DATE
> Task :unityLibrary:generateDebugResources UP-TO-DATE
> Task :unityLibrary:packageDebugResources UP-TO-DATE
> Task :unityLibrary:extractDeepLinksDebug UP-TO-DATE
> Task :launcher:generateDebugResValues UP-TO-DATE
> Task :launcher:generateDebugResources UP-TO-DATE
> Task :unityLibrary:compileDebugLibraryResources UP-TO-DATE
> Task :launcher:mergeDebugResources UP-TO-DATE
> Task :launcher:createDebugCompatibleScreenManifests UP-TO-DATE
> Task :launcher:extractDeepLinksDebug UP-TO-DATE
> Task :launcher:mergeDebugShaders UP-TO-DATE
> Task :launcher:compileDebugShaders NO-SOURCE
> Task :launcher:generateDebugAssets UP-TO-DATE
> Task :launcher:processDebugJavaRes NO-SOURCE
> Task :launcher:checkDebugDuplicateClasses UP-TO-DATE
> Task :launcher:checkDebugAarMetadata
> Task :unityLibrary:generateDebugBuildConfig UP-TO-DATE
> Task :unityLibrary:javaPreCompileDebug UP-TO-DATE
> Task :unityLibrary:mergeDebugShaders UP-TO-DATE
> Task :unityLibrary:compileDebugShaders NO-SOURCE
> Task :unityLibrary:generateDebugAssets UP-TO-DATE
> Task :unityLibrary:processDebugManifest
> Task :unityLibrary:parseDebugLocalResources
> Task :unityLibrary:packageDebugAssets
> Task :unityLibrary:processDebugJavaRes UP-TO-DATE
> Task :unityLibrary:bundleLibResDebug UP-TO-DATE
> Task :unityLibrary:mergeDebugJniLibFolders UP-TO-DATE
> Task :launcher:processDebugMainManifest
> Task :unityLibrary:mergeDebugNativeLibs
> Task :launcher:processDebugManifest
> Task :unityLibrary:generateDebugRFile
> Task :launcher:mergeDebugAssets
> Task :launcher:compressDebugAssets
> Task :unityLibrary:copyDebugJniLibsProjectOnly
> Task :launcher:mergeDebugJavaResource

> Task :unityLibrary:compileDebugJavaWithJavac FAILED

> Task :launcher:processDebugManifestForPackage
> Task :launcher:desugarDebugFileDependencies
34 actionable tasks: 15 executed, 19 up-to-date

0x00007ff677c78e4d (Unity) StackWalker::GetCurrentCallstack
0x00007ff677c7ddf9 (Unity) StackWalker::ShowCallstack
0x00007ff678c4b121 (Unity) GetStacktrace
0x00007ff67930d922 (Unity) DebugStringToFile
0x00007ff676bc97f6 (Unity) DebugLogHandler_CUSTOM_Internal_Log
0x0000022ebe2d1c93 (Mono JIT Code) (wrapper managed-to-native) UnityEngine.DebugLogHandler:Internal_Log (UnityEngine.LogType,UnityEngine.LogOption,string,UnityEngine.Object)
0x0000022ebe2d1bcb (Mono JIT Code) UnityEngine.DebugLogHandler:LogFormat (UnityEngine.LogType,UnityEngine.Object,string,object[])
0x0000022ebe2d1950 (Mono JIT Code) UnityEngine.Logger:Log (UnityEngine.LogType,object)
0x0000022fc8811bb5 (Mono JIT Code) UnityEngine.Debug:LogError (object)
0x0000022fc88116b3 (Mono JIT Code) UnityEditor.Android.GradleInvokationException:ParseAndShowException ()
0x0000022f92327423 (Mono JIT Code) UnityEditor.Android.PostProcessor.PostProcessRunner:RunAllTasks (UnityEditor.Android.PostProcessor.PostProcessorContext)
0x0000022fc87d8fb3 (Mono JIT Code) UnityEditor.Android.PostProcessAndroidPlayer:PostProcess (UnityEditor.Modules.BuildPostProcessArgs,AndroidPlayerBuildProgram.Data.AndroidPlayerBuildProgramOutput)
0x0000022fc8790db3 (Mono JIT Code) UnityEditor.Android.AndroidBuildPostprocessor:PostProcess (UnityEditor.Modules.BuildPostProcessArgs,UnityEditor.BuildProperties&)
0x0000022fc8790481 (Mono JIT Code) UnityEditor.PostprocessBuildPlayer:Postprocess (UnityEditor.BuildTargetGroup,UnityEditor.BuildTarget,int,string,string,string,int,int,UnityEditor.BuildOptions,UnityEditor.RuntimeClassRegistry,UnityEditor.Build.Reporting.BuildReport)
0x0000022fc87907f5 (Mono JIT Code) (wrapper runtime-invoke) <Module>:runtime_invoke_void_int_int_int_object_object_object_int_int_int_object_object (object,intptr,intptr,intptr)
0x00007ffe788de0d4 (mono-2.0-bdwgc) mono_jit_runtime_invoke (at C:/build/output/Unity-Technologies/mono/mono/mini/mini-runtime.c:3445)
0x00007ffe7881eb74 (mono-2.0-bdwgc) do_runtime_invoke (at C:/build/output/Unity-Technologies/mono/mono/metadata/object.c:3066)
0x00007ffe7881ed0c (mono-2.0-bdwgc) mono_runtime_invoke (at C:/build/output/Unity-Technologies/mono/mono/metadata/object.c:3113)
0x00007ff677b97bc4 (Unity) scripting_method_invoke
0x00007ff677b76844 (Unity) ScriptingInvocation::Invoke
0x00007ff6796823b1 (Unity) CallMono
0x00007ff67968b267 (Unity) PostprocessPlayer
0x00007ff679685653 (Unity) DoBuildPlayer_PostBuild
0x00007ff67968374e (Unity) DoBuildPlayer
0x00007ff679677085 (Unity) BuildPlayer
0x00007ff67741432f (Unity) BuildPipeline::BuildPlayerInternalNoCheck
0x00007ff6771a4ffc (Unity) BuildPipeline_CUSTOM_BuildPlayerInternalNoCheck
0x0000022f16d14927 (Mono JIT Code) (wrapper managed-to-native) UnityEditor.BuildPipeline:BuildPlayerInternalNoCheck (string[],string,string,UnityEditor.BuildTargetGroup,UnityEditor.BuildTarget,int,UnityEditor.BuildOptions,string[],bool)
0x0000022f16d140f3 (Mono JIT Code) UnityEditor.BuildPlayerWindow/DefaultBuildMethods:BuildPlayer (UnityEditor.BuildPlayerOptions)
0x0000022f16d104bb (Mono JIT Code) UnityEditor.BuildPlayerWindow:CallBuildMethods (bool,UnityEditor.BuildOptions)
0x0000022ec951fc43 (Mono JIT Code) UnityEditor.BuildPlayerWindow:BuildPlayerAndRun (bool)
0x0000022eea9971d3 (Mono JIT Code) UnityEditor.BuildPlayerWindow:GUIBuildButtons (UnityEditor.Modules.IBuildWindowExtension,bool,bool,bool,UnityEditor.Build.BuildPlatform,UnityEditor.Modules.IBuildPostprocessor)
0x0000022ec95177fb (Mono JIT Code) UnityEditor.BuildPlayerWindow:ShowBuildTargetSettings ()
0x0000022ec8408f9b (Mono JIT Code) UnityEditor.BuildPlayerWindow:OnGUI ()
0x0000022ebd2d2892 (Mono JIT Code) UnityEditor.HostView:InvokeOnGUI (UnityEngine.Rect)
0x0000022fbc33cbf3 (Mono JIT Code) UnityEditor.DockArea:DrawView (UnityEngine.Rect)
0x0000022fbc333883 (Mono JIT Code) UnityEditor.DockArea:OldOnGUI ()
0x0000022ebb920a1f (Mono JIT Code) UnityEngine.UIElements.IMGUIContainer:DoOnGUI (UnityEngine.Event,UnityEngine.Matrix4x4,UnityEngine.Rect,bool,UnityEngine.Rect,System.Action,bool)
0x0000022ebb91e65b (Mono JIT Code) UnityEngine.UIElements.IMGUIContainer:HandleIMGUIEvent (UnityEngine.Event,UnityEngine.Matrix4x4,UnityEngine.Rect,System.Action,bool)
0x0000022ebb91db7b (Mono JIT Code) UnityEngine.UIElements.IMGUIContainer:HandleIMGUIEvent (UnityEngine.Event,System.Action,bool)
0x0000022ebb91da03 (Mono JIT Code) UnityEngine.UIElements.IMGUIContainer:HandleIMGUIEvent (UnityEngine.Event,bool)
0x0000022ebb91d60b (Mono JIT Code) UnityEngine.UIElements.IMGUIContainer:SendEventToIMGUIRaw (UnityEngine.UIElements.EventBase,bool,bool)
0x0000022ebb91d503 (Mono JIT Code) UnityEngine.UIElements.IMGUIContainer:SendEventToIMGUI (UnityEngine.UIElements.EventBase,bool,bool)
0x0000022eb363a673 (Mono JIT Code) UnityEngine.UIElements.IMGUIContainer:ProcessEvent (UnityEngine.UIElements.EventBase)
0x0000022eb363a253 (Mono JIT Code) UnityEngine.UIElements.CallbackEventHandler:HandleEvent (UnityEngine.UIElements.EventBase)
0x0000022eb3639f8f (Mono JIT Code) UnityEngine.UIElements.CallbackEventHandler:HandleEventAtCurrentTargetAndPhase (UnityEngine.UIElements.EventBase)
0x0000022eb3639d13 (Mono JIT Code) UnityEngine.UIElements.CallbackEventHandler:HandleEventAtTargetPhase (UnityEngine.UIElements.EventBase)
0x0000022ebb91c21b (Mono JIT Code) UnityEngine.UIElements.MouseCaptureDispatchingStrategy:DispatchEvent (UnityEngine.UIElements.EventBase,UnityEngine.UIElements.IPanel)
0x0000022eb4a200ae (Mono JIT Code) UnityEngine.UIElements.EventDispatcher:ApplyDispatchingStrategies (UnityEngine.UIElements.EventBase,UnityEngine.UIElements.IPanel,bool)
0x0000022eb477fa1b (Mono JIT Code) UnityEngine.UIElements.EventDispatcher:ProcessEvent (UnityEngine.UIElements.EventBase,UnityEngine.UIElements.IPanel)
0x0000022eb22854d3 (Mono JIT Code) UnityEngine.UIElements.EventDispatcher:ProcessEventQueue ()
0x0000022eb2285343 (Mono JIT Code) UnityEngine.UIElements.EventDispatcher:OpenGate ()
0x0000022eb228529b (Mono JIT Code) UnityEngine.UIElements.EventDispatcherGate:Dispose ()
0x0000022eb477fef3 (Mono JIT Code) UnityEngine.UIElements.EventDispatcher:ProcessEvent (UnityEngine.UIElements.EventBase,UnityEngine.UIElements.IPanel)
0x0000022eb477c073 (Mono JIT Code) UnityEngine.UIElements.EventDispatcher:Dispatch (UnityEngine.UIElements.EventBase,UnityEngine.UIElements.IPanel,UnityEngine.UIElements.DispatchMode)
0x0000022eb477beeb (Mono JIT Code) UnityEngine.UIElements.BaseVisualElementPanel:SendEvent (UnityEngine.UIElements.EventBase,UnityEngine.UIElements.DispatchMode)
0x0000022ebb902213 (Mono JIT Code) UnityEngine.UIElements.UIElementsUtility:DoDispatch (UnityEngine.UIElements.BaseVisualElementPanel)
0x0000022ebb901b43 (Mono JIT Code) UnityEngine.UIElements.UIElementsUtility:UnityEngine.UIElements.IUIElementsUtility.ProcessEvent (int,intptr,bool&)
0x0000022ebb90193f (Mono JIT Code) UnityEngine.UIElements.UIEventRegistration:ProcessEvent (int,intptr)
0x0000022ebb90187b (Mono JIT Code) UnityEngine.UIElements.UIEventRegistration/<>c:<.cctor>b__1_2 (int,intptr)
0x0000022ebb9016cd (Mono JIT Code) UnityEngine.GUIUtility:ProcessEvent (int,intptr,bool&)
0x0000022ebb901786 (Mono JIT Code) (wrapper runtime-invoke) <Module>:runtime_invoke_void_int_intptr_intptr& (object,intptr,intptr,intptr)
0x00007ffe788de0d4 (mono-2.0-bdwgc) mono_jit_runtime_invoke (at C:/build/output/Unity-Technologies/mono/mono/mini/mini-runtime.c:3445)
0x00007ffe7881eb74 (mono-2.0-bdwgc) do_runtime_invoke (at C:/build/output/Unity-Technologies/mono/mono/metadata/object.c:3066)
0x00007ffe7881ed0c (mono-2.0-bdwgc) mono_runtime_invoke (at C:/build/output/Unity-Technologies/mono/mono/metadata/object.c:3113)
0x00007ff677b97bc4 (Unity) scripting_method_invoke
0x00007ff677b76844 (Unity) ScriptingInvocation::Invoke
0x00007ff677b71495 (Unity) ScriptingInvocation::Invoke<void>
0x00007ff677cc356a (Unity) Scripting::UnityEngine::GUIUtilityProxy::ProcessEvent
0x00007ff6786b6518 (Unity) GUIView::ProcessRetainedMode
0x00007ff678c7d414 (Unity) GUIView::OnInputEvent
0x00007ff6786b6463 (Unity) GUIView::ProcessInputEventFromAPI
0x00007ff6786b6338 (Unity) GUIView::ProcessInputEvent
0x00007ff678c7e21c (Unity) GUIView::ProcessEventMessages
0x00007ff678c77fa5 (Unity) GUIView::GUIViewWndProc
0x00007ffef6ac8211 (USER32) DispatchMessageW
0x00007ffef6ac7cd1 (USER32) DispatchMessageW
0x00007ff678c51693 (Unity) MainMessageLoop
0x00007ff678c56910 (Unity) WinMain
0x00007ff67a04133e (Unity) __scrt_common_main_seh
0x00007ffef75326ad (KERNEL32) BaseThreadInitThunk
0x00007ffef89eaa68 (ntdll) RtlUserThreadStart
```

2:
[image]

3:

```
CommandInvokationFailure: Gradle build failed. 
C:\Program Files\Unity\Hub\Editor\2022.3.5f1\Editor\Data\PlaybackEngines\AndroidPlayer\OpenJDK\bin\java.exe -classpath "C:\Program Files\Unity\Hub\Editor\2022.3.5f1\Editor\Data\PlaybackEngines\AndroidPlayer\Tools\gradle\lib\gradle-launcher-7.2.jar" org.gradle.launcher.GradleMain "-Dorg.gradle.jvmargs=-Xmx4096m" "assembleDebug"

Environment Variables:
__PSLockDownPolicy = 0
USERDOMAIN = TOMICA-BRPO
ProgramFiles = C:\Program Files
LAUNCH_DARKLY_CLIENT_TOKEN = 60a7e30fafc7e60e33446283
TMP = C:\Users\bruno\AppData\Local\Temp
PROCESSOR_ARCHITECTURE = AMD64
PROCESSOR_REVISION = 6001
OS = Windows_NT
CHROME_CRASHPAD_PIPE_NAME = \\.\pipe\crashpad_4044_TPIZLSLYSGMNWFZH
PROCESSOR_IDENTIFIER = AMD64 Family 23 Model 96 Stepping 1, AuthenticAMD
ProgramW6432 = C:\Program Files
USERPROFILE = C:\Users\bruno
JAVA_HOME = C:\Program Files\Unity\Hub\Editor\2022.3.5f1\Editor\Data\PlaybackEngines\AndroidPlayer\OpenJDK
CommonProgramFiles = C:\Program Files\Common Files
DriverData = C:\Windows\System32\Drivers\DriverData
ComSpec = C:\WINDOWS\system32\cmd.exe
AMPLITUDE_API_KEY = 28f3cae0b33b8b3702120c9ed1a935aa
PSModulePath = C:\Program Files\WindowsPowerShell\Modules;C:\WINDOWS\system32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\Modules
ANDROID_NDK_ROOT = C:\Program Files\Unity\Hub\Editor\2022.3.5f1\Editor\Data\PlaybackEngines\AndroidPlayer\NDK
SystemRoot = C:\WINDOWS
HEAP_CLIENT_TOKEN = 1717415662
NUMBER_OF_PROCESSORS = 6
AMPLITUDE_API_KEY_STAGING = 83ee04fccc67e4fcc7dd527c4c6f1e21
WOOTRIC_CLIENT_TOKEN = NPS-aa8be4c3
JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS = -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8
DEBUG_ENV_VAR = UnityHub
BURST_ANDROID_MIN_API_LEVEL = 22
EFC_6804 = 1
TEMP = C:\Users\bruno\AppData\Local\Temp
Path = C:\Program Files (x86)\NVIDIA Corporation\PhysX\Common;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-18.0.2.1\bin;C:\Program Files\Common Files\Oracle\Java\javapath;C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Oracle\Java\javapath;C:\Program Files\Eclipse Adoptium\jdk-17.0.1.12-hotspot\bin;C:\WINDOWS\system32;C:\WINDOWS;C:\WINDOWS\System32\Wbem;C:\WINDOWS\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\WINDOWS\System32\OpenSSH\;C:\Program Files\nodejs\;C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\150\Tools\Binn\;C:\Program Files\dotnet\;C:\msys64\mingw64\bin;C:\Program Files\Git\cmd;;C:\WINDOWS\system32;C:\WINDOWS;C:\WINDOWS\System32\Wbem;C:\WINDOWS\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\WINDOWS\System32\OpenSSH\;C:\Program Files\Git LFS;C:\Users\bruno\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Scripts\;C:\Users\bruno\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\;C:\Users\bruno\scoop\shims;C:\Users\bruno\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\Scripts\;C:\Users\bruno\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\;C:\Users\bruno\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps;C:\Users\bruno\AppData\Local\GitHubDesktop\bin;C:\Users\bruno\AppData\Roaming\npm;C:\Users\bruno\AppData\Local\Programs\Microsoft VS Code\bin;C:\Users\bruno\.dotnet\tools;;C:\Users\bruno\AppData\Local\Programs\oh-my-posh\bin;C:\Users\bruno\AppData\Local\Programs\oh-my-posh\themes;C:\Program Files (x86)\GitHub CLI\;C:\Users\bruno\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps;C:\Program Files\Neovim\bin;C:\Users\bruno\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WinGet\Packages\BurntSushi.ripgrep.MSVC_Microsoft.Winget.Source_8wekyb3d8bbwe\./ripgrep-13.0.0-x86_64-pc-windows-msvc;
USERNAME = bruno
COMPUTERNAME = TOMICA-BRPO
PATHEXT = .COM;.EXE;.BAT;.CMD;.VBS;.VBE;.JS;.JSE;.WSF;.WSH;.MSC
SystemDrive = C:
ALLUSERSPROFILE = C:\ProgramData
SENTRY_ACCESS_TOKEN = 3df78d9e53f8456aa90fbae044ce1a6261421ab1d0014674bc2e933477289017
HEAP_CLIENT_TOKEN_STAGING = 3786794399
windir = C:\WINDOWS
HOMEPATH = \Users\bruno
PUBLIC = C:\Users\Public
CommonProgramFiles(x86) = C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files
APPDATA = C:\Users\bruno\AppData\Roaming
OneDrive = C:\Users\bruno\OneDrive
PROCESSOR_LEVEL = 23
CommonProgramW6432 = C:\Program Files\Common Files
ProgramFiles(x86) = C:\Program Files (x86)
SESSIONNAME = Console
GIT_LFS_PATH = C:\Program Files\Git LFS
LOGONSERVER = \\TOMICA-BRPO
LOCALAPPDATA = C:\Users\bruno\AppData\Local
VBOX_HWVIRTEX_IGNORE_SVM_IN_USE = 1
VBOX_MSI_INSTALL_PATH = C:\Program Files\Oracle\VirtualBox\
LAUNCH_DARKLY_CLIENT_TOKEN_STAGING = 60a7e30fafc7e60e33446282
HOMEDRIVE = C:
USERDOMAIN_ROAMINGPROFILE = TOMICA-BRPO
ProgramData = C:\ProgramData
ORIGINAL_XDG_CURRENT_DESKTOP = undefined


stderr[
Picked up JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS: -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8
C:\Users\bruno\GOLDEN_GOOSE\GOLDEN GOOSE\Library\Bee\Android\Prj\Mono2x\Gradle\unityLibrary\src\main\java\com\unity\androidnotifications\UnityNotificationManager.java:164: error: cannot find symbol
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.TIRAMISU)
                                                        ^
  symbol:   variable TIRAMISU
  location: class VERSION_CODES
C:\Users\bruno\GOLDEN_GOOSE\GOLDEN GOOSE\Library\Bee\Android\Prj\Mono2x\Gradle\unityLibrary\src\main\java\com\unity\androidnotifications\UnityNotificationManager.java:165: error: cannot find symbol
            permissionGranted = mContext.checkCallingOrSelfPermission(Manifest.permission.POST_NOTIFICATIONS) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED;
                                                                                         ^
  symbol:   variable POST_NOTIFICATIONS
  location: class permission
Note: C:\Users\bruno\GOLDEN_GOOSE\GOLDEN GOOSE\Library\Bee\Android\Prj\Mono2x\Gradle\unityLibrary\src\main\java\com\unity3d\player\UnityPlayerActivity.java uses or overrides a deprecated API.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.
Note: Some input files use unchecked or unsafe operations.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:unchecked for details.
2 errors

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':unityLibrary:compileDebugJavaWithJavac'.
> Compilation failed; see the compiler error output for details.

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 9s
]
stdout[
Exception while marshalling C:\Program Files\Unity\Hub\Editor\2022.3.5f1\Editor\Data\PlaybackEngines\AndroidPlayer\SDK\build-tools\32.0.0\package.xml. Probably the SDK is read-only
Exception while marshalling C:\Program Files\Unity\Hub\Editor\2022.3.5f1\Editor\Data\PlaybackEngines\AndroidPlayer\SDK\platform-tools\package.xml. Probably the SDK is read-only
Exception while marshalling C:\Program Files\Unity\Hub\Editor\2022.3.5f1\Editor\Data\PlaybackEngines\AndroidPlayer\SDK\platforms\android-31\package.xml. Probably the SDK is read-only
Exception while marshalling C:\Program Files\Unity\Hub\Editor\2022.3.5f1\Editor\Data\PlaybackEngines\AndroidPlayer\SDK\platforms\android-32\package.xml. Probably the SDK is read-only
Exception while marshalling C:\Program Files\Unity\Hub\Editor\2022.3.5f1\Editor\Data\PlaybackEngines\AndroidPlayer\SDK\tools\package.xml. Probably the SDK is read-only
Exception while marshalling C:\Program Files\Unity\Hub\Editor\2022.3.5f1\Editor\Data\PlaybackEngines\AndroidPlayer\SDK\build-tools\32.0.0\package.xml. Probably the SDK is read-only
Exception while marshalling C:\Program Files\Unity\Hub\Editor\2022.3.5f1\Editor\Data\PlaybackEngines\AndroidPlayer\SDK\platform-tools\package.xml. Probably the SDK is read-only
Exception while marshalling C:\Program Files\Unity\Hub\Editor\2022.3.5f1\Editor\Data\PlaybackEngines\AndroidPlayer\SDK\platforms\android-31\package.xml. Probably the SDK is read-only
Exception while marshalling C:\Program Files\Unity\Hub\Editor\2022.3.5f1\Editor\Data\PlaybackEngines\AndroidPlayer\SDK\platforms\android-32\package.xml. Probably the SDK is read-only
Exception while marshalling C:\Program Files\Unity\Hub\Editor\2022.3.5f1\Editor\Data\PlaybackEngines\AndroidPlayer\SDK\tools\package.xml. Probably the SDK is read-only
> Task :launcher:preBuild UP-TO-DATE
> Task :unityLibrary:preBuild UP-TO-DATE
> Task :launcher:preDebugBuild UP-TO-DATE
> Task :unityLibrary:preDebugBuild UP-TO-DATE
> Task :launcher:mergeDebugNativeDebugMetadata NO-SOURCE
> Task :unityLibrary:compileDebugAidl NO-SOURCE
> Task :launcher:generateDebugBuildConfig UP-TO-DATE
> Task :unityLibrary:packageDebugRenderscript NO-SOURCE
> Task :launcher:compileDebugAidl NO-SOURCE
> Task :unityLibrary:writeDebugAarMetadata UP-TO-DATE
> Task :launcher:compileDebugRenderscript NO-SOURCE
> Task :unityLibrary:compileDebugRenderscript NO-SOURCE
> Task :launcher:javaPreCompileDebug UP-TO-DATE
> Task :unityLibrary:generateDebugResValues UP-TO-DATE
> Task :unityLibrary:generateDebugResources UP-TO-DATE
> Task :unityLibrary:packageDebugResources UP-TO-DATE
> Task :unityLibrary:extractDeepLinksDebug UP-TO-DATE
> Task :launcher:generateDebugResValues UP-TO-DATE
> Task :launcher:generateDebugResources UP-TO-DATE
> Task :unityLibrary:compileDebugLibraryResources UP-TO-DATE
> Task :launcher:mergeDebugResources UP-TO-DATE
> Task :launcher:createDebugCompatibleScreenManifests UP-TO-DATE
> Task :launcher:extractDeepLinksDebug UP-TO-DATE
> Task :launcher:mergeDebugShaders UP-TO-DATE
> Task :launcher:compileDebugShaders NO-SOURCE
> Task :launcher:generateDebugAssets UP-TO-DATE
> Task :launcher:processDebugJavaRes NO-SOURCE
> Task :launcher:checkDebugDuplicateClasses UP-TO-DATE
> Task :launcher:checkDebugAarMetadata
> Task :unityLibrary:generateDebugBuildConfig UP-TO-DATE
> Task :unityLibrary:javaPreCompileDebug UP-TO-DATE
> Task :unityLibrary:mergeDebugShaders UP-TO-DATE
> Task :unityLibrary:compileDebugShaders NO-SOURCE
> Task :unityLibrary:generateDebugAssets UP-TO-DATE
> Task :unityLibrary:processDebugManifest
> Task :unityLibrary:parseDebugLocalResources
> Task :unityLibrary:packageDebugAssets
> Task :unityLibrary:processDebugJavaRes UP-TO-DATE
> Task :unityLibrary:bundleLibResDebug UP-TO-DATE
> Task :unityLibrary:mergeDebugJniLibFolders UP-TO-DATE
> Task :launcher:processDebugMainManifest
> Task :unityLibrary:mergeDebugNativeLibs
> Task :launcher:processDebugManifest
> Task :unityLibrary:generateDebugRFile
> Task :launcher:mergeDebugAssets
> Task :launcher:compressDebugAssets
> Task :unityLibrary:copyDebugJniLibsProjectOnly
> Task :launcher:mergeDebugJavaResource

> Task :unityLibrary:compileDebugJavaWithJavac FAILED

> Task :launcher:processDebugManifestForPackage
> Task :launcher:desugarDebugFileDependencies
34 actionable tasks: 15 executed, 19 up-to-date
]
exit code: 1
UnityEditor.Android.Command.WaitForProgramToRun (UnityEditor.Utils.Program p, UnityEditor.Android.Command+WaitingForProcessToExit waitingForProcessToExit, System.String errorMsg) (at <8575ccd599f94176ac54c3e24a897458>:0)
UnityEditor.Android.Command.Run (System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo psi, UnityEditor.Android.Command+WaitingForProcessToExit waitingForProcessToExit, System.String errorMsg) (at <8575ccd599f94176ac54c3e24a897458>:0)
UnityEditor.Android.Command.Run (System.String command, System.String args, System.String workingdir, UnityEditor.Android.Command+WaitingForProcessToExit waitingForProcessToExit, System.String errorMsg) (at <8575ccd599f94176ac54c3e24a897458>:0)
UnityEditor.Android.AndroidJavaTools.RunJava (System.String args, System.String workingdir, System.Action`1[T] progress, System.String error) (at <8575ccd599f94176ac54c3e24a897458>:0)
UnityEditor.Android.GradleWrapper.Run (UnityEditor.Android.AndroidJavaTools javaTools, Unity.Android.Gradle.AndroidGradle androidGradle, System.String workingdir, System.String task, System.Action`1[T] progress) (at <8575ccd599f94176ac54c3e24a897458>:0)
Rethrow as GradleInvokationException: Gradle build failed
UnityEditor.Android.GradleWrapper.Run (UnityEditor.Android.AndroidJavaTools javaTools, Unity.Android.Gradle.AndroidGradle androidGradle, System.String workingdir, System.String task, System.Action`1[T] progress) (at <8575ccd599f94176ac54c3e24a897458>:0)
UnityEditor.Android.PostProcessor.Tasks.BuildGradleProject.Execute (UnityEditor.Android.PostProcessor.PostProcessorContext context) (at <8575ccd599f94176ac54c3e24a897458>:0)
UnityEditor.Android.PostProcessor.PostProcessRunner.RunAllTasks (UnityEditor.Android.PostProcessor.PostProcessorContext context) (at <8575ccd599f94176ac54c3e24a897458>:0)
UnityEngine.GUIUtility:ProcessEvent(Int32, IntPtr, Boolean&)
```

I use the SDK, JDK, NDK and gradle installed with unity:
[image]

If there is anything else I should show here, please let me now.

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Screenshot 2 seems quite clear on the error.

Comment: @BugFinder I am not entirely sure if I know what that means. Should I install java and use that with unity?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The API level of Android Tiramisu is 33, so at least you need to install the Android SDK version 33. BTW if you can't upgrade the Android SDK with UnityHub, try to use Android Studio, and don't forget to change the Target API level in the Android Player settings.