# Build failed with an exception (2 errors)

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, build, classpath

When I try to build the app, it throws me an error:

FAIL: Build failed with exception.

- Where:
  File 'C:\Users\Lukáš\Fart button\Library\Bee\Android\Prj\IL2CPP\Gradle\launcher\build.gradle' line: 1
- What went wrong:
  A problem occurred while evaluating the ':launcher' project.

> Failed to use plugin [id 'com.android.internal.application'].
> Your project path contains non-ASCII characters. This will most likely cause the build to fail in Windows. Please move the project to another directory. Please see http://b.android.com/95744 for details. This warning can be turned off by adding the line 'android.overridePathCheck=true' to the gradle.properties file in the project directory.

- Try:
  Run with the --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with the --info or --debug option to get the next log output. Execute with the --scan option to get a full report.

Also:

E:\Unity\2021.3.21f1\Editor\Data\PlaybackEngines\AndroidPlayer\OpenJDK\bin\java.exe -classpath "C:\Grandle\gradle-6.1.1\lib\gradle-launcher-6.1.1.jar" org.gradle.launcher.GradleMain "-Dorg.gradle.jvmargs=-Xmx4096m" "assembleRelease"

I've been trying to solve this for a week now and have no idea what to do. I've tried everything...

I tried several times to reinstall all packages (ndk, jdk, sdk) - nothing helped. But what I found, the program can't use the plugin. I think
it is simply looking for another way, other than the Adroid studio repository where the plugins are downloaded (in a folder). But then I don't know what else to do..

Answer (score 0):

I once had a problem similar to this (I can not remember the exact error) My solution was building to my "Downloads" folder. That worked for some reason. I was able to move the build to mt "Builds" folder after it finished the build.

EDIT: I just found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76793778/22037861). It might be able to fix your problem